# Ayuda con cronometro en Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

En una columna del datatable, se pone la hora, si esta activo se vuelve un cronometro, el problema esta que el primer valor que encuentra solo ese repite en las demás celdas de la columna, por ejemplo la hora en la celda 1 es 09:25:45 y si activo el cronometro en las otras celdas me muestra este primer valor en todas esas celdas, como puedo hacer que me muestre independientemente el valor en cada celda, a continuación expongo mi código (mi columna del tiempo es la 3 y la columna que activa el cronómetro es el 8):

```
$('#procestables').dataTable(
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    ///extrayendo hora minutos y segundos
    devhor=devuelvehora(aData[3]);
    devmin=devuelveminuto(aData[3]);
    devseg=devuelvesegundo(aData[3]);

      if(aData[8]=="f") {
          //activando el cronometro en funcion a la hora minuto y segundo recuperado de la celda
           setInterval( function () {
              devseg=devseg+1;
                 if(devseg>=60){
                  devseg=0;
                  devmin=devmin+1;
                  }
                 if(devmin>=60)
                 {devmin=0;
                  devhor=devhor+1;
               }
      //aqui retornamos el valor en el datatable del ahora minuto y segundo 
                $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html("<h4 style='color:#000000'>"+devhor+":"+devmin+":"+devseg+"</h4>" );
      },1000 );
  }
 else
  { //si es falso no se activa el cronometro
      $('td:eq(3)', nRow).html("<h4           style='color:#000000'>"+devhor+":"+devmin+":"+devseg+"</h4>");
  }       
});
```